# react-native Reload Flastlist per each new Focus

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist

How to Reload a Screen When web back to screen for second time (in tab navigator):

```
   export default class BasketTab1 extends React.PureComponent  {

   componentDidMount () {


       this.getProductsRequest();//retur
    }

    getProductsRequest(){

    }

    render() {
       return (

        <View style={{margin:5}}>
          <FlatList
            data={this.state.products}
             renderItem={this.renderItem}
             keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
             extraData={this.state}
             ...)
     }

}
```

I try
set extra data to a boolean value.

```
extraData={this.state.refresh}
```

And Toggle the value of boolean state when I want to refresh list

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        refresh : false
    }
}
componentDidMount () {

this.didFocusListener = this.props.navigation.addListener(
  'didFocus',
  () => { this.setState({
      refresh: !this.state.refresh
  }) },
);
this.getProductsRequest();
}
```

But no reload/not happen anything!

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
this.didFocusListener = this.props.navigation.addListener(
'didFocus',
   () => { this.setState({
  refresh: !this.state.refresh, products: [...this.state.products]
  }) },
);
```